# Docker: Cannot start container [8] System error: invalid argument

Tags: docker

Im trying to map the following directories from my host machine inside my docker container.

Host:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Sep 16 07:34 /.PowerFolder
```

Docker container:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Sep 20 09:21 /home/root/.PowerFolder
```

I'm using the following command:

```
docker run -dit --net="bridge" -P --name "powerfolder_client" -v /.PowerFolder:/home/root/.PowerFolder -v /mnt/HD/HD_a2/PowerFolders:/home/root/PowerFolders a6eeb8313ff9
```

And face the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 99442f0230bb009eb9da82ac64142042aa6c9f58a67565881f0d000a78af7a1e: [8] System error: invalid argument
```

If I leave the first `-v` argument and execute the `docker run` command likes this:

```
docker run -dit --net="bridge" -P --name "powerfolder_client" -v /mnt/HD/HD_a2/PowerFolders:/home/root/PowerFolders a6eeb8313ff9
```

The container runs fine and the second mapping is accomplished correctly! So there seems to be a problem with the first `-v` mapping argument.

I've already checked the permissions in and outside the container and checked if the directories exist on both sides. I don't get what I'm missing here. Isn't docker allowed to map hidden directories?